# PHP mkdir( $recursive = true ) skips last directory

Tags: php, recursion, path, filesystems, mkdir

I've got the following piece of code on a PHP 5.2.4 (no safe_mode) linux server:

```
mkdir( $path, 0777, true );
```

when I enter a path like:

```
'/path/to/create/recur/ively/'
```

all directories are created except for the last one...
when I add another directory like:

```
'/path/to/create/recur/ively/more/'
```

again, all paths are created except for the last one...

have tried both with and without trailing slashes

Can any1 enlighten me here please?

Comment: Please post the exact version of PHP you're using. Also, is your host running with safe_mode enabled?

Comment: What's your error_reporting level? If something goes wrong an E_WARNING is raised. safe mode is off, but does your php version contain something like suhosin? How (and from where) did you install php? Compiled from "vanilla" php.net sources? Through your distribution's package manger (which one is it and what's the exact name of the package)? The function php_plain_files_mkdir() (responsible for the php function mkdir(x,y,true)) hasn't changed quite a while and I haven't found a related bug at http://bugs.php.net

Comment: So, let me sum up: the question is "recursive mkdir doesn't work properly", and the answer is "oh golly, I made a mistake and deleted the directory later in the code". Then I really wonder why this user has got 26 upvotes for this valuable information?  I don't think 14 other people had the same problem...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok the solutions is as follows: there was no problem.

I did not test the code in isolation, but only assumed the following code was not doing anything to the directory structure...

as I found out the directory got deleted later on by the code itself.

Anyway, Lesson learned...

Answer (score 8):

Try to remove the trailing slash from your path.

At least that's how it's being used in the examples of the `mkdir` documentation.

Personally I can't remember having problems, but I usally don't append trailing slashes, so go and try that.

**UPDATE**:

I just tried your code and it created every directory including the last one.
I'm running Mac OS X 10.5. No idea why it's not working for you :-(

That's the code I used:

```
<?php
$path = '/Users/andre/test/bla/foo';
mkdir( $path, 0777, true );
```

Sorry, seems like I'm of no help here.

Answer (score 2):

If you tried everything and it keeps not working, then add some text in the end of the path like:

```
$path = '/path/to/create/recur/ively/more/this_wont_be_created_anyway';
```

Comment: That's how I 'solved' it in the current code...
But it doesn't really make any sense...

Comment: thats a dirty work-around and does not help the question asked...
> Can any1 enlighten me here please?

Comment: @Sophomore - enlighten you with what?

Comment: @Andre - agree totally. else side effects might just trigger.

Comment: I agree this is a work-around but hey, he said he tested the solutions that people had posted already

Answer (score 2):

The intermediate directories created are set based on the current umask. You want something like this

```
umask(0777);
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your PHP version? Is safe_mode turned on?

If so, then it could be that you are experiencing http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43276

Comment: 5.2.4 without safe_mode, so it's not applicable, I've also tried with and without trailing slashes so....

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this error if you make the silly mistake I did and pass a string, rather than the numeric literal for mode.

```
mkdir( $path, "0777", true ); // BAD - only creates /a/b

mkdir( $path, 0777, true ); // GOOD - creates /a/b/c/d
```

Answer (score 0):

Function that create all directories (folders) of given path. No need to write code create each directories (folders) of given path. it will create all directories (folders).

Like : If you want to create directory structure like 
**organizations / 1 / users / 1 /**

So you only need to call this function with directories path like 
**$directories_path = 'organizations/1/users/1/';

createUploadDirectories($directories_path);**

```
/*
* Method Name : createUploadDirectories
* Parameter : null
* Task : Loading view for create directries for upload
*/

if ( ! function_exists('createUploadDirectories')){
    function createUploadDirectories($upload_path=null){
        if($upload_path==null) return false;
        $upload_directories = explode('/',$upload_path);
        $createDirectory = array();
        foreach ($upload_directories as $upload_directory){
            $createDirectory[] = $upload_directory;
            $createDirectoryPath = implode('/',$createDirectory);
            if(!is_dir($createDirectoryPath)){
                $old = umask(0); 
                mkdir($createDirectoryPath,DIR_WRITE_MODE);// Create the folde if not exist and give permission
                umask($old); 
            }               
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```