# How to tell php to create a directory and another directory inside that one

Tags: php

How do I tell php to create a directory and then another directory inside that directory?

I'm using mkdir here. I have a folder called images. I need to create a folder inside images called 'user', then a folder under user called '15'. I can create the folder called user in one go. How can I do both together?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can pass the [`recursive` parameter as `true`](http://php.net/mkdir);

```
mkdir('images/user/15', 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the recursive flag of mkdir function

The function signature is:

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

So use it like so

```
mkdir('images/user/15',0777,true);
```

Though it is also advisable not to use 777 mode, but that is another matter.

Answer (score 3):

Try `mkdir('path/to/file', 0777, true);`

mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )

Read more @ [PHP mkdir( $recursive = true ) skips last directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399174/php-mkdir-recursive-true-skips-last-directory)

Answer (score 1):

```
$the_path = '/user/15';
$the_mode = '0700';
mkdir($the_path,$the_mode, true);
```

you can generate the required path & permissions for the new directory, pass them to the mkdir function along with setting the 'recursive' flag to true.

Answer (score 1):

This code will create the directories in recursive way with same permission you define like 0777

```
umask(0777);
mkdir('images/user/15', 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newdir="user";
$subdir="15";
//fetch the current working directory
$curdir= getcwd();
// append the "images" directory to your current working directory 
$dir=$curdir."\images";
// append the "$newdir" directory to your image directory path 
$path=$dir."/$newdir"; 
// for the two line u can write $dir= $curdir."\images"."/$newdir";
// check if file exits
if(is_dir($path)) //or using the single  line code if(is_dir($dir))
{
    echo "directory exists";
}
else
{
    mkdir($path."/$subdir",0777,true);
    echo " directory Created";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use is_dir and mkdir

```
if (!is_dir($path)) 
{
   @mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php